# File(image) is not stored to the local storage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to sore an image file to my local storage in order to reuse it on a different page. Im getting a picture or a file when on desktop. That should be transferred to a file and then I want to store it the `onImagePicked` function. I have connected that function with a button so the image should be transformed to a file and also be stored then. But somehow the func. is not called because I don't get my `console.log`. I suppose it could have to do something that Im just testing with pictures that come directly from my desktop and not with pictures from a device. But I don't know.

Here is my code: (The rest with getting and displaying the picture works)

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


// convert base64 image into a file
function base64toBlob(base64Data, contentType) {
  contentType = contentType || '';
  const sliceSize = 1024;
  const byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
  const bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
  const slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
  const byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);

  for (var sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex < slicesCount; ++sliceIndex) {
    const begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
    const end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);

    const bytes = new Array(end - begin);
    for (let offset = begin, i = 0; offset < end; ++i, ++offset) {
      bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);
    }
    byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);
  }
  return new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
}


export const IMAGE_DATA = 'image_data';
...
@ViewChild('filePicker') filePickerRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @Output() imagePick = new EventEmitter<string | File>();
  selectedImage: string;
  usePicker = false;
...
 takePicture() {
    if (this.usePicker) {
      this.filePickerRef.nativeElement.click();
    }
    Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 80,
      source: CameraSource.Prompt,
      correctOrientation: true,
      saveToGallery: true,
      allowEditing: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
      direction: CameraDirection.Front
    }).then(image => {
      this.selectedImage = image.base64String;
      this.imagePick.emit(image.base64String);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    });
  }

  onImagePicked(imageData: string | File) {
    let imageFile;
    if (typeof imageData === 'string') {
      try {
      imageFile = base64toBlob(imageData.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', ''), 'image/jpeg');
      this.storage.set('image_data', imageFile);
      console.log('stored');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      imageFile = imageData;
    }
  }

  onFileChosen(event: Event) {
    const pickedFile = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = () => {
      const dataUrl = fr.result.toString();
      this.selectedImage = dataUrl;
      this.imagePick.emit(pickedFile);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(pickedFile);
  }
```

html (where I try to call the function)

```
 <app-make-photo (imagePick)="onImagePicked($event)"></app-make-photo>
```

Comment: I'm confused: your are calling `onImagePicked()` with no arguments on the button click. Where should the `imageData` come from? I think it's undefined.

Comment: so what would I have to define?

Comment: I think you should call `onImagePicked` from `onFileChosen` and from the success handler of `Plugins.Camera.getPhoto().then(successHandler)` and `takePicture` from your html template.

Comment: I actually made a component for the camera and created a own listenable event for the onImagePicked with this` @Output() imagePick = new EventEmitter<string | File>();` function but I get the error that onImagePicked is not a func. I updated my answer

Comment: In which file is `onImagePicked($event)` placed? could it be that `onImagePicked($event)` is in the wrong component class?

Comment: photo.page.html where I make use of my make-photo component. the strange thing is that other functions of the component work but not this one

Comment: any chance to share your code on https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-camera ?